# Multiple forms on one MVC form, created with a loop, only the first submits data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code, only the first form submits anything, the following submit null values, each model has data. If I change it to just one large form, everything submits. Why do the other individual forms post null values?

**View**

```
@model myModel[]
<ul>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("controllerAction", "Controller", FormMethod.Post,
                               new { id="Form"+i }))
        {
            <li>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[i].property1)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(a => a[i].property2)
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a[i].property3)
                <input type="submit" />
            </li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult controllerAction(myModel[] models)
{
    ...do stuff...
}
```

Comment: only form that contains clicked submit button submited to server

Comment: @ConvertToInt32 That is only happening with the first form, and the first submit button, the following forms post null values when their submit buttons are clicked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that your creating form controls with indexers in your `for` loop, and your POST method parameter is `myModel[] models`.

By default, the `DefaultModelBinder` requires collection to be zero based and consecutive, so if you attempt to submit the second form, your posting back `[1].property1: someValue` etc. Because the indexer starts at 1, binding fails and the model is `null`.

You can solve this by adding a hidden input for an `Index` property used by the model binder to match up non consecutive indexers

```
<li>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[i].property1)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(a => a[i].property2)
    @Html.HiddenFor(a => a[i].property3)
    <input type="hidden" name="Index" value="@i" /> // add this
    <input type="submit" />
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this is saving me big time!

Comment: if you collection is child collection then name should be name ="childvarname.index" where childvarname is name of property for child collection in your variable